# Is there a resource anywhere that lists every spell and the classes that can use them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

There are now a number of resources that provide lists of spells; the PHB, Tasha's Cauldron, XGtE, *etc*. There are also spells that are included in specific adventures or campaign books.

There are also new classes that come with new spell rules; the artificer is one.

Is there a single, official D&D resource anywhere that lists all the spells currently published for 5th edition, the classes they can be used by and their level? I now own 10 books and having to juggle between that various changes to spell lists is getting more and more complicated. For instance, the Bard has access to additional spells as listed in XGtE and Tasha's Cauldron.

I am looking for an official list, similar to the one published in the PHB, that details for every class the spells that they have access to including all currently official published spells.

Comment: Are you just looking for a list of the names of each spell available to each class, or do you want a source that also gives the full text for each spell?

Comment: Just a list, I have all the books but at the moment have to navigate between them to get the full list of spells each class can access.

Comment: I have specifically stated an official resource?

Comment: I’m up-voting this question because it's clearly asking for resources that you don't have to pay for. /s

Comment: The comment I made about DnD beyond was based on a mistaken belief that I would have to re buy the books I have physical copies of in order to use it simply for a full and complete list. 

I am surprised Wizards of the coast have not published a full reference list online as a free resource to build on the list on the PHB. as stated I am not looking for the spell rules, just an updated list I can provide my players rather then me have to manually create it by going through every book I own.

Comment: You have all the books.  I don't see a problem that requires solving.

Comment: having to manually go through every book and work out all the spells available to a bard for instance means that at the table my players have to have 3 books open when working out which spells they will prepare that is the problem. It also means i have to double check in 3 locations when working out which spells my NPC's have access to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd point you to D&D's official resource website [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells). This provides a searchable, filterable listing of every spell in all officially published material. You may only view the spell descriptions of spells which are available in the SRD (because the rest, you have to pay for in order to see), but it at least tells you where to find them.

Comment: What I am looking for is not a list of all spells, I am looking for a single point to view all the official spells by class, effectively the class spell lists in the PHB updated with all spells available in all official published books.

Comment: @RichardC if you use the filter option on D&D Beyond you can filter by class, then sort by level and you have exactly that

Comment: Is this even with only the free access account? For instance will that include the list for an artificer, and the spells added in XGTE?

Comment: @RichardC Yep, it works without an account. You don't even need a free access one. I verified that by logging out of dndbeyond and checking.